# Google js file not loading on runtime

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, google-api, google-font-api

### I am trying to include these files from google API, but when I run my file I can't > find them including in the head of the file

```
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com
    /css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700,300italic,400italic,500italic,700italic' 
    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0
   /jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the link 
    http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700,300italic,400italic,500italic,700italic
in the browser

Do a 'save as' on the resulting webpage that contains the media css.

Assuming you have saved it as 'file.css'

```
<link href='file.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Do the same for the 'jquery.min.js' file and change you script tag as follows:Assuming you have saved it as 'file.js'

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
```

This way you have both the files locally and don't have to depend on the internet to download them every time.